# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment error

Tags: python, arrays

`sig_txt: [45 67 83 32767 101 90 50]`

`idx_rr:[101] // index after 32767`

`sig: [45 67 83 101 90 50] // all the elements except 32767`

Basically what happens is from the original array, all except the element whose value is equal to **32767** is passed to the `sig` array. And `idx_rr` gets the value immediate after **32767**. I have written a python for the same. But I am getting this error:

> "'int' object does not support item assignment"

when I am trying to plot the `idx_rr` value of `sig`. Can I get some help on this.

```
R_peak = False   
j = 0
k = 0
idx_rr = []
sig = []

for i in range (len(sig_txt)):
    if (sig_txt[i] == 32767):
        idx_rr = i+1
        idx_rr[j] = np.array(sig_txt[i+1])
        sig = i+1
        sig[k] = np.array(sig_txt[i+1])
        k = k + 1
        j = j + 1
        print(idx_rr)
        R_peak = True
    else:
        if (R_peak == False):
            sig = i
            sig[k] = np.array(sig_txt[i])
            k = k + 1

        else:
            R_peak = False

plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.plot(sig)
plt.scatter([idx_rr], [sig[idx_rr]], c='g')  
plt.show() 

TypeError Traceback (most recent   call last)
<ipython-input-1474-dcea2717b9f2> in <module>
----> 1 get_intervals('/home/yasaswini/hp2-notebooks/ecg_data   
/Recorded_Data_Patch_Simulator/TXT_Files   
/ECG_data_128Hz_Simulator_Patch_Normal_data.txt',128)

<ipython-input-1471-5a6b384defd1> in get_intervals(fname,sampling_rate)
22             if (R_peak == False):
23                 sig = i
---> 24                 sig[k] = np.array(sig_txt[i])
25                 k = k + 1
26 

TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: `idx_rr = i+1` is assigning the index after 32767 to idx_rr.

Comment: I think that there are a lot of errors in this program, so you should not expect any of the answers below to fix all of them, just the error you quote.

Comment: Please update your question with the full traceback of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `idx_rr = i+1` the formerly defined `list` becomes an `int` so there's no index `idx_rr[j]` to assign a value to. The same applies to the `sig` variable.

Note that the problem is not the declaration, python allows you to re-assign a variable to a new type. The problem is that `idx_rr` is of type `int` and you cannot access and index `idx_rr[j]` of an `int`.

Try this

```
R_peak = False   
j = 0
k = 0
idx_rr = []
idx_rr_int = 0
sig = []
sig_int = 0
for i in range (len(sig_txt)):
    if (sig_txt[i] == 32767):
        idx_rr_int = i+1
        idx_rr[j] = np.array(sig_txt[i+1])
        sig_int = i+1
        sig[k] = np.array(sig_txt[i+1])
        k = k + 1
        j = j + 1
        print(idx_rr_int)
        R_peak = True
    else:
        if (R_peak == False):
            sig_int = i
            sig[k] = np.array(sig_txt[i])
            k = k + 1

        else:
            R_peak = False

plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.plot(sig)
plt.scatter([idx_rr], [sig[idx_rr]], c='g')  
plt.show()
```

Comment: I should think that the quoted error actually occurs first just after ‘sig = i’ for the same reason.

Comment: I included `idx_rr = i+1` because when I print `idx_rr`, I need to get the `sig_txt` index which is after the value  32767. I removed the list declaration of `idx_rr` and `sig_txt` but the error still remains.

Comment: @Jasmin, then use a different variable for the `idx_rr = i+1` assignment... and `sig=i+1` of course

Answer (score 0):

After the line `idx__rr = i+1`, you are changing the data type of idx_rr, which was list previously, to **int**.

Change the variable name of the list to get rid of the error.