# list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python, arrays

This question is the continuation [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58989570/typeerror-int-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-error/58992194#58992194). The `idx_rr` is throwing an error. I know this error is because `idx_rr` is a list and it is being assigned as an index for `sig`. But I am not sure how to clear it. Can I get something on this?

```
N = len(sig_txt)  
R_peak = False   
j = 0
k = 0
idx_rr = [0 for l in range(N)]
idx_rr_int = 0
sig = [0 for m in range(N)]
sig_int = 0
#print(len(sig_txt))
for i in range (len(sig_txt)):
    if (sig_txt[i] == 32767):
        idx_rr[k] = np.array(i)
        sig[j] = np.array(sig_txt[i+1])
        k = k + 1
        j = j + 1
        R_peak = True
    else:
        if (R_peak == False):
            sig_int = i
            #print(j)
            #print(sig_txt[i])
            sig[j] = np.array(sig_txt[i])
            j = j + 1
        else:
            R_peak = False

#print(idx_rr)
#print(sig)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.plot(sig)
plt.scatter([idx_rr], [sig[idx_rr]], c='g')  
plt.show() 


TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-387-dcea2717b9f2> in <module>
----> 1 get_intervals('/home/yasaswini/hp2-notebooks/ecg_data/Recorded_Data_Patch_Simulator  
/TXT_Files/ECG_data_128Hz_Simulator_Patch_Normal_data.txt',128)

<ipython-input-384-606e74089dfb> in get_intervals(fname, sampling_rate)
     38     plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
     39     plt.plot(sig)
     ---> 40     plt.scatter([idx_rr], [sig[idx_rr]], c='g')
     41     plt.show()
     42 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: "I know this error is because `idx_rr` is a list and it is being assigned as index for `sig`" - now that you know it... would you care to explain what exactly you are hoping to achieve by passing a list where an index is needed???

Comment: There are more appropriate [resources](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for bug-fixing your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasmine, this works, though i think you still need to make a few changes:

```
N = len(sig_txt)  
R_peak = False   
j = 0
k = 0
idx_rr = [0 for l in range(N)]
idx_rr_int = 0
sig = [0 for m in range(N)]
sig_int = 0
#print(len(sig_txt))
for i in range (len(sig_txt)):
    if (sig_txt[i] == 32767):
        idx_rr[k] = np.array(i)
        sig[j] = sig_txt[i+1]
        k = k + 1
        j = j + 1
        R_peak = True
    else:
        if (R_peak == False):
            sig_int = i
            #print(j)
            #print(sig_txt[i])
            sig[j] = sig_txt[i]
            j = j + 1
        else:
            R_peak = False

#print(idx_rr)
#print(sig)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.plot(sig)
plt.scatter(idx_rr, sig, c='g')  
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

@goodvibration, I get your point. This is my final code. I am getting the expected result. Thank you for the pointers.

```
def ECG_marker_remove(sig_txt):
N = len(sig_txt)  
j = 0
k = 0
idx_rr = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.int32)
sig = np.zeros(N)
for i in range (N):
    if (sig_txt[i] == 32767):
        if (j == N-1):
            sig[j] = 0
            idx_rr[k] = 0
            j = j + 1
            k = k + 1
        else:
            sig[j] = sig_txt[i+1]
            idx_rr[k] = i
            j = j + 1
            k = k + 1
    else:
        sig[j] = sig_txt[i]
        j = j + 1
idx_rr_peaks = idx_rr[:k]
return sig, idx_rr_peaks
```